# How to disable HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 protocols in Chrome permanently?

Tags: android, google-chrome, config, chromium

I need to permanently disable all modern protocols in Chrome for Android for testing purposes. I know that on the desktop version I can pass `--disable-http2` and `--disable-quick` parameters when starting. I have root access, is it possible to do this by correcting the configuration files or something else?